# github project not launching as web app inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I have eclipse mars installed with the egit plugin.  It successfully downloads projects from github, but **how do I convert the downloaded github projects into eclipse maven web projects that can successfully launch via `Run As ... Run on server` in eclipse?**

Let's take [this two step authentication project on github](https://github.com/kyleboon/two-step-authentication-example) as an example.  **How do I get [this project](https://github.com/kyleboon/two-step-authentication-example) to launch from eclipse using `Run As.. Run on server`?**

Here are the steps I took so far:

1.) Right click on white background of eclipse Project Explorer.

2.) Choose `Import > Import ...`

3.) Select `Git > Projects` from git from the resulting dialog box
Click Next

4.) Select `Clone URI` then click next again

5.) Enter the following in the URI field: `https://github.com/kyleboon/two-step-authentication-example`

6.) Click Next

7.) Click Next Again

8.) Click Next a Third time

9.) Select `Import` using the `new project wizard`.  Then click next again.

10.) Select `maven project` and `import`

11.) Right click on root of resulting project in eclipse Project Explorer and choose `Properties`.

12.) Select `Project Facets`

13.) Enable `Project Facets`

14.) Select `Dynamic Web Module` to make it a `dynamic web project`. Click OK.

15.) Right click on project root in eclipse Project Explorer.  Select `Maven download sources`, then `Maven update project`.

16.) Right click on project root in eclipse and choose `Run As...Run on server`

The result is that tomcat gives a 404 error when it launches the following url: `http://localhost:8080/two-step-authentication-example/`

**So what steps do I do instead in order to successfully launch this specific github project in eclipse using Run As...Run on Server?**  This question is general for all github web projects, but we are using this specific project as a case study to test a method that will be repeatable for other github projects.

Comment: The project you linked to is a Gradle, not a Maven, project.

Comment: @Tunaki Then show how to do it with the gradle eclipse plugin